# RobotFramework: Keyword 'Selenium2Library.Input Text' expected 2 arguments, got 1

Tags: selenium-webdriver, robotframework

I am trying to setup a automaited test. I am useing RobotFramework and the Selenium2Library.

When I run the test, I get `Keyword 'Selenium2Library.Input Text' expected 2 arguments, got 1` for the line:

```
Input Text    id=quota 128
```

What am I doing wrong? I googled around and cannot find an answer. :(

The instructions I have are http://rtomac.github.io/robotframework-selenium2library/doc/Selenium2Library.html

Comment: Ok just found the answer:
this:
Input Text    id=quota 128

needs to be this:
Input Text    id=quota    128

Need four spaces.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Arguments must be separated by at least two spaces, so

```
Input Text    quota    128
```

will do.